# Анимация появления блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px 0 #b8c0d0;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 110px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.card:hover .info {
  display: block;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background: wheat;
}

.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="icon">
    Icon
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="name">
      <b>John Doe</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      Frontend Developer
    </p>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Высоту блока card задал фиксированной, чтобы не было лишнего дерганья

info должен появляться плавно справа налево и весь блок обертка card тоже двигается справа налево

Сложность заключается в том, что у card не будет фиксированной ширины, а width auto не анимируется.

Нужно чтобы при наведении на icon появлялся выезжая текст справа налево (с классом info. И сам блок card двигался справа налево

До наведения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После - плавное появление справа налево:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос в  чем ?...

Comment: @Дмытрык добавил более подробное описание

Answer (score 3):

Можно отделаться одним лишь `transform:translate`

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 13px 0 #b8c0d0;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 110px;
  transition: all .2s;
  transform:translate(160px,0);
  transition:300ms;
}
.card:hover{
  transform: translate(0,0)
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="icon">
    Icon
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p class="name">
      <b>John Doe</b>
    </p>
    <p>
      Frontend Developer
    </p>
      
  </div>
</div>
```